# laravel pasar parametros de variable en boton

Tags: php, html, laravel

En la rejilla de un CRUD tengo en la parte de arriba al lado del título un botón buscar.
En ese botón voy al método correspondiente en el controlador, pero pasandole el id del registro.
He puesto esto:

```
<a class='btn btn-info' href='{{ route('productos.show',$producto->id) }}' style='text-align:right'>BUSCAR</a>
```

En el método index del controlador tengo esto:

```
$productos=\App\Producto::get();
        return view('productos.index')->with('productos',$productos);
```

Y en web.php esto:

```
Route::get('/',function () {
    return view('productos/index');
});
//rutas para todo el crud
Route::resource('productos','ProductoController');
```

Me da el siguiente error:
"Undefined variable: producto (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ad\dam2d\resources\views\productos\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Podrias poner el código de la View donde pasas el array Productos a el item "producto", supongo que tendrás un
 ```
    @foreach ($productos as $producto)
       ...code
       <a class='btn btn-info' href='{{ route('productos.show',$producto->id) }}' style='text-align:right'>BUSCAR</a>
    @endforeach
``

Comment: El código no cabe aquí, si tengo un foreach, hay alguna manera de pasar todo el código?

Comment: no se si se puede poner todo el código (supongo que no), me refiero al código de desde el foreach hasta cuando pasas los datos al botón.
Entiendo que imprimiendo en la vista la variable productos tiene datos y cuando usas el foreach y crees la variable "productos" supongo que también.

Comment: Hasta el foreach: $sql="SELECT * FROM productos";
   $resul=mysqli_query(conectar(),$sql);
   echo "<table class='table' border='1'>";
   echo "<tr><td colspan=3 align='center'><b>PRODUCTOS</b>&nbsp<a class='btn btn-info' href='{{ route('productos.show',$producto->id) }}' style='text-align:right'>BUSCAR</a></td><td><a class='btn btn-success' href='nuevo.php' style='text-align:right'>NUEVO</a></td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Precio</th><th>Acciones</th></tr>";

Comment: foreach($productos as $producto)?>
    <tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $producto->id }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $producto->nombre }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $producto->precio }}</td>
    <td>
     <a class='btn btn-warning' href='{{ route('productos.edit',$producto->id,$producto->nombre,$producto->precio) }}'>EDITAR</a>&nbsp
     <a class='btn btn-danger' href='{{ route('productos.delete',$producto->id,$producto->nombre,$producto->precio) }}'>ELIMINAR</a>
    </td>
    </tr>

Comment: Normalmente, el método `index` es para listar los elementos de una tabla. Si tienes el botón de buscar al lado del título (de la página, supongo), ¿estás seguro de que encuentra dentro del bucle `foreach($productos as $producto)`? Tampoco entiendo, si es un botón para buscar, que le pongas directamente un ID de producto predefinido.

Comment: He podido arreglar ese fallo, ahora me aparece bien la plantilla y encuentra registros el buscar. El error ahora es que tanto al pulsar el botón nuevo como el buscar me llevan los dos a la vista buscar (show), aunque tienen una vista diferente adjudicada.